# scope of 'everybody': infelicitous use of 'it'

Tags: pronouns, semantics

Irene Heim claims the second 'it' is not felicitously used in this sequence of words. It must sound awkward.

1. Everybody found a cat and kept it. ***It*** ran away. (source: (5) on page 225 of '[File Change Semantics and the Familiarity Theory of Definiteness](http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/hyper/heim1983.pdf)')

What would be an alternative then? My mind tells me 'the cat' and 'the cats' work here, depending, respectively, if they found one cat together, or if each of them found one cat, with possibility of some of them sharing one here and there.

Does connecting the two sentences solve the problem?

2. Everybody found a cat and kept it, and ***it*** ran away.
3. Everybody found a cat, kept it, and ***it*** ran away.

Also, I think splitting the first sentence makes the first 'it' infelicitous too. Am I right?

4. Everybody found a cat. They kept ***it***. ***It*** ran away.

Comment: I think the problem with this example is that you can view it as a singular cat, which I don't believe Irene Heim intended. Try *"Everybody bought a hat and wore it. It fell apart in the first rainstorm."*

Comment: +1 Peter. In order for the first sentence to express a general truth, it needs to be recast in the present perfect. *Everybody has found a cat and kept it.* (I.e. We've all experienced finding a stray animal and keeping it.) As a specific truth it makes no sense, since everyone cannot find a single cat.  The second sentence is a specific, not a general truth. As such it would be a non-sequitur to general truth expressed with "everybody has found"; and since the specific truth version of the first sentence (Everybody found) is gibberish, the second sentence has no cogent point of departure.

Comment: Everyone has found a cat and kept it, only to have it run away.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Heim is wrong about this example. I don't know why the *it* is infelicitous in the Original example, but it doesn't seem to be for any of the reasons Heim gives. The reason for my saying this is that the *it* sounds ok in the following examples:

- Everybody found a cat and kept it. It always ran away the following day.
- Everybody found a cat and kept it. More often than not, it ran away the following day.
- Everybody found a cat and kept it. Invariably, it ran away.

The occurrences of 'it' in the Original Poster's examples (2) and (4) seem more or less felicitous to me too.

Comment: How about substituting 'the cat' or 'the cats' for the second 'it' in example (1)? Does it do any job? (I'm a non-native speaker of English)

Comment: @Sssamy If you substituted *cat* for *cats* and used the pronoun *them* it would work. But then that no longer tells you anything about the scope of *everybody*.

Comment: Thanks, I meant to ask you if 'The cat ran away,' or 'The cats ran away,' would make sense, without changing anything in the first sentence. ('the cat' --- there is a slim chance they found one cat together, you know)

Comment: I think the problem here is the use of the word _everybody_.  This makes the entire statement unclear. I'm not sure if a group of people found a single cat, or each individual found a single cat, or as a group they found multiple cats... In fact, I'm not sure of the point, other than to say that cats do not like people. ;-)

Comment: I looked at the source, and it's so opaque that I can't really be surel, but I think she's just considering the case where there are multiple cats. A clearer example would be *"Everybody bought a hat and wore it. It fell apart in the first rainstorm."*

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, but even if there are multiple cats, the second and third sentences in my examples seem felicitous.

Comment: I'd agree. Your examples seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Your examples are all fine, but I think they reframe the semantics of the statements. Heim’s example reads to me as a description of a singular event when everybody (whoever context dictates that to be here) found themselves a cat, and the cats that they found ran away in a singular event as well. That does jar. Your versions change it to a habitual, repeated, general, or usual collection of events, each of which is regularly followed by another event, which is a different thing.

Comment: An example that provides a bit more context and then forces the semantic framing of Heim’s statement more vigorously would be something like: “The shooter came into the classroom and started shooting wildly around. Everybody cowered under a table for protection. It was too thin to withstand the bullets.” — If we assume that everybody didn't cower under one big table, the _it_ in the second sentence is very infelicitous to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Yes, but that's orthoganal to Heim's point. Heim is arguing that  the first *it* is not a referring expression (so she says) and that this is the reason why the *it* in the second sentence is infelicitous. The second, sentence-initial *it*, she says, must be referrential. In my examples, the *it*s are comparable in this respect. Heim's claim is just plain wrong.